# Is it possible to have a linked list, with each element in the list being its own array?

Tags: arrays, pointers

**Expansion on the title**

---

We're learning about linked lists, and I was wondering if it would be useful at all to have a linked list with many arrays linked together. We were talking about the inefficiency of lengthening an array and I thought that this would be a possibility.

---

**Example:**
*Assume you have int values stored with 4 bytes for an int and 4 bytes for the pointer*

---

At address 200 you have array A which has 24 elements in the array and the one pointer to the address of the next array.

**Edit for clarity:** Array A will take up 100 bytes, going up to address 300. Between 300 and 548 there are other data. I want to make array A longer, but the address at 300 is taken, so it goes to the next free space at 548. Array A then gets a pointer to address 548 so that it can have more elements

At address 548 you have array B with 11 elements and a pointer.
You make a linked list with Array A pointer pointing to Array B.
Would it then be easy to search through the array normally instead of sequentially, making it faster or am I completely mistaken?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, this design might be more efficient for some reasons. 
1. You don't have to repeatedly allocate new memory space. This is able to alleviate memory fragmentation problem.
2. The data locality in the memory is better and thereby improving cache hit rate.

A similar design is B+tree. You may take a look at how B+tree works.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "yes". It's not immediately clear what language you are proposing to do this in, but it's certainly possible.

What's not so clear is whether it is any more efficient - that really depends on what you are trying to do. If each array is the same then why are they broken up and linked? Is this to allow searching in parallel?

Comment: ah, I see. Presumably this is some sort of embedded or other highly contrained environment. But yes, it works as an idea, sure.